# iOS JPG File Association using Swift 2

Tags: jpeg, xcode7, file-association

I have an iOS Project I'm working on using `Xcode7` and Swift2. I have file association working great on it with `PDF` files. I did this in my `Info.plist`. I want to now associate it with images, particularly with `JPG` images.  I have looked online and cannot find anything for this. Can someone please help?

For PDF I have:

[image]

Which looks like this in Source Code:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>PDFIcon64.png</string>
            <string>PDFIcon320.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

I tried copying the above and adjusting for JPG with no luck:

```
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>JPGIcon64.JPG</string>
            <string>JPGIcon320.JPG</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>JPEG</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.xyz.JPG</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

I also tried this instead with no luck:

```
   <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.JPG</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.JPG</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

When I'm viewing an image in my iOS Photo Library and click on the action button, it does not list my app in the area where the Message, Facebook, Twitter, etc. apps are located, like it does with `PDF` files from my Mail app. I've looked online in all kinds of forums with no luck for this.

Comment: This is really not swift or swift2 related, please update your tags

Answer (score 0):

For images that will be stores with the app you should consider using an Asset Catalog.

There is one asset catalog that defaults to every project and you can store images in there.

Once you add as asset to the catalog you can reference it in a string by the name you have it (without its extension).

```
 For example 
 UIImage(named: "JPGIcon64")
```

Here is the link to the apple doc that talks about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/Recipe.html)